# Hive SQL query json result and display keys as columns

Tags: sql, json, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table with one column that contains a JSON object as string:

```
json1

{"key1" : "val1", "key2:"val2"}
{"key1" : "val1", "key2:"val4"}
{"key2" : "val2", "key3:"val3"}
```

I am currently using the built-in json_tuple function to query the key-value pair as such:

```
SELECT json1 FROM TABLENAME
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(TABLENAME.json1,'key2') jsontable as column1 
where column1="val2"
```

And I am getting a result like this:

```
{"key1" : "val1", "key2:"val2"}
{"key2" : "val2", "key3:"val3"}
```

How can I display the result with keys as columns and the values as rows:

```
key1   key2   key3
val1   val2   NULL
NULL   val2   val3
```

I have over 100 distinct keys in the JSON objects so hard-coding it is not an option, I also tried using `split(json1)` that returned a list with each key-value pair but I could not display the keys as columns, any help will be appreciated!